# My result is 1 but the length of string i entered is longer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int length(char *point)
{
    int n=0;


    if (*point!='\0')
    {
        point++;
        n++;
    }
    return n;

}
void main()
{

    int m;
    char *point;
    char chars[80];
    printf ("please enter a chars\n");
    gets(chars);
    point=chars;
    m=length(chars);

    printf("The length of the chars is %d.\n",m);

}
```

I want to ask why the "n" can't be added?
I think the problem is about the use of point,but i can't find it.
Thanks.

Comment: and if you use built-in function `strlen` instead of custom one `length`?

Comment: `int main(void)` and a `return 0` would be better too.

Comment: @Badda `int main()` is a MUST (_almost_), while `return 0;` is entirely optional. :)

Comment: You can drop the `point` variable here. It has no purpose.

Comment: Plus never use `gets` as it has been deprecated and it is dangerous. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used

Answer (score 6):

```
size_t length(const char *point)
{
    size_t n = 0;       
    while (*point != '\0') // Need to loop to iterate through point
    {
        point++;
        n++;
    }
    return n;
}
```

I would use it in the `main` like that :

```
int main(void)
{
    char chars[80];
    printf ("Please enter a chars\n");

    scanf("%79s", chars); 
    // The 79 is there to limit the input to the size you allocated in chars[80]
    // Thus avoiding buffer overflow

    size_t m = length(chars);
    printf("The length of the chars is %zu.\n",m);
    return 0;
}
```

You forget to iterate through the string. You incremented the pointer but that's all. Also, I recommend using `strlen()` which does exactly what you intend to do.

Using `strlen()`:

```
int main(void)
{
    char chars[80];
    printf ("Please enter a chars\n");
    scanf("%79s", chars);
    size_t m = strlen(chars);
    printf("The length of the chars is %zu.\n", m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also I would use `size_t length(const char* point)` over `size_t length(char* point)` for const correctness, since you're not changing the characters.

Comment: @AndreKampling You are correct. I just have a little doubt, isn't it `char const* point` to make a const string ?

Comment: Pointer to const char: `const char* point` == `char const* point`. The only diffrence is: `char* const point` where the pointer is constant to a non const char.

Comment: @tilz0R: No it isn't he changed `if` with `while`.

Comment: @AndreKampling right now there is an `if` in the question. Could not spot any `while`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Question: `if (*point!='\0')` != This answer: `while (*point != '\0')`. Am I blind?

Comment: @AndreKampling sorry I misunderstood your comment, forget it.

Comment: `scanf("%s", &chars);` → `scanf("%79s", chars);`. `%s` expects a `char*`, not a `char (*)[80]`

Comment: @CoolGuy Ok for the `&`. So `"%79s"` limits the string to 79 char ? I didn't know that

Comment: Yes. Its the length specifier and tells `scanf` to read at most 79 (in this case) characters (+1 for the NUL-terminator `\0`), thus preventing buffer overflows

Comment: I used while instead of if and it worked .Thanks for all of your answers.

Comment: @chux Thanks. Accordingly to that meta post, I thought pasting it as a comment on the post would be the best.

Comment: Maybe after a fews days.  IAC, you are on way up - patience.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a loop inside your function `length()`. The `if` is only evaluated once.

Add (or replace the `if` with) a loop statement

```
/* loop */ {
    if (*point!='\0') { /* ... */ }
}
```